# setInterval based timer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a timer similar to the one on [qqtimer.net](http://qqtimer.net)
The behavior of the timer is as follows:

- Timer displays 0 on page load.
- Upon space being pressed, timer starts counting up.
- Upon space being pressed again, timer stops and displays time.
- Upon space being pressed again, timer resets and starts,

and so on and so forth. From my research, it seems the best way to do this is with `setInterval` and `document.onkeypress`. Here's my code so far:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="main.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timer">
       0
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var running = false;
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    if (running) {
      clearInterval(refresh);
    } else {
      var startTime = new Date().getTime();
      var refresh = window.setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
      }, 100);
    }
  }
};
```

This code works fine for the timer starting, but stopping it doesn't seem to work. It never ends the original `setInterval`, so the third space press starts another `setInterval` at the same time.

Multiple guides I've looked at say that `clearInterval(refresh)` should stop the interval, but that doesn't seem to be true.

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: move refresh outside of your event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason was that you were declaring refresh inside of the if statment, so it was unavailable when you tried to clear it. Check out this working example below.

```
var running = false;
var refresh;
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    if (running) {
      clearInterval(refresh);
      running = false;
    } else {
      var startTime = new Date().getTime();
      refresh = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
      }, 100);
      running = true;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @JulianLachniet Make sure to approve his answer so he gets credit